# Promise inside Angular.forEach

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I'm new to Angular and promises altogether and tried to look for the existing posts regarding but I could not understand much.. 
My problem is  I've a list (schedulesLst) and I'm iterating inside it to get related data, add it to the fresh list.

```
$scope.sessionLst=[];
  function createSession(scheduleLst){
  var session={};
  var sessionLst=[];
    angular.forEach(scheduleLst, function(sch){
      Jobschedule.findById({
        id:sch.id
      }).$promise.then(function (data) {
        session=data;
        session.ambassadorid=sch.ambassadorId;
        session.status=CoreService.jobStatus.Assigned;
      });
      sessionLst.push(session);
    });
    $scope.sessionLst=sessionLst;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Nizet, Sorry for taking much time to mark it as answer. Been busy with aother tasks. Now I had some knowledge of promises and this make sense to me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var session={};
var sessionLst=[];
angular.forEach(scheduleLst, function(sch){
  Jobschedule.findById({
    id:sch.id
  }).$promise.then(function (data) {
    session=data;
    session.ambassadorid=sch.ambassadorId;
    session.status=CoreService.jobStatus.Assigned;
  });
  sessionLst.push(session);
});
```

Let's analyze the above code.

You create **an** empty object: `session`.

Then you create an empty array: `sessionLst`.

Then, for each element of `scheduleLst`, you do something.

At each iteration, you call `Jobschedule.findById`. Later, when the promise is resolved, something will happen. But in the meantime, you push the empty `session` object in `sessionLst`.

So you end up with a list containing the same empty session object several times.

Now some times passes, and the promises end up being resolved. They each reassign the `session` variable, but leave the array as is.

What you in fact want is to have many session objects, and they should go in the array once you get them from the resolved promise:

```
var sessionLst = [];
angular.forEach(scheduleLst, function(sch){
  Jobschedule.findById({
    id:sch.id
  }).$promise.then(function (data) {
    var session = data;
    session.ambassadorid = sch.ambassadorId;
    session.status = CoreService.jobStatus.Assigned;
    sessionLst.push(session);
  });
});
```

This might be what you want, but it might not be: the sessionLst won't be in the same order that the seceduleLst, and if any of the promises fails, you'll lose the session and won't be aware. So maybe $q.all is what you want. But at least, you should get the idea of what is wrong with your current implementation.

Comment: Are you sure .$promise.then() is correct and not just .then()?

Comment: @GONeale it correct, because OP seems to have `$resource` implementation for making rest calls inside `Jobschedule` service `findById` method **OR** it can be Restangular too..

Answer (score 0):

If `findById()` is returning a true promise, just `.then` should be needed with the following code:

```
$scope.sessionLst=[];
function createSession(scheduleLst) {
    var session = {};
    var sessionLst = [];
    angular.forEach(scheduleLst, function (sch) {
        Jobschedule.findById({
            id: sch.id
        }).then(function (data) {
            session = data;
            session.ambassadorid = sch.ambassadorId;
            session.status = CoreService.jobStatus.Assigned;
            $scope.sessionLst.push(session);
        });
    });
}
```

For more information on $q read the documentation - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: The famous defer antipattern. This new promise is useless. read my answer for a similar, but simpler alternative, that doesn't need a new defer.

Comment: True actually :) It doesn't.

Comment: Fixed. I still believe `$promise` is not needed so therefore not included in my version.

Comment: Looks to me like the OP is using a `$resource` service that returns objects with a `$promise` property. For more information on objects returned by `$resource` methods see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource